# SELECT query for recursive table with names from another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- First: (`id`, `names`)
- Second (which is recursive, for hierarchical purposes): (`id`, `idsub`)

How do I display names for every id and idsub?

Comment: select * from first left join second on first.id=second.id

Comment: This just joins the tables, I want to substitute keys from the second table with the values from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display 4-depth hierarchy, you can use self-join on `second_table` and get names from sub query on `first_table`. You can try something like this.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT f.names FROM first_table AS f WHERE f.id=s1.id) AS lvl1_names,
  (SELECT f.names FROM first_table AS f WHERE f.id=s2.id) AS lvl2_names,      
  (SELECT f.names FROM first_table AS f WHERE f.id=s3.id) AS lvl3_names,
  (SELECT f.names FROM first_table AS f WHERE f.id=s4.id) AS lvl4_names
FROM second_table AS s1
LEFT JOIN second_table AS s2 ON s1.id = s2.idsub
LEFT JOIN second_table AS s3 ON s2.id = s3.idsub
LEFT JOIN second_table AS s4 ON s3.id = s4.idsub
```

If you have more simple data structure such
`first_table (id, names, parent)` then you can simplify it and avoid sub query. Something like this.

```
SELECT 
  f1.names AS lvl1_names,
  f2.names AS lvl2_names,
  f2.names AS lvl3_names,
  f3.names AS lvl4_names
FROM first_table AS f1
LEFT JOIN first_table AS f2 ON f1.parent = f2.id
LEFT JOIN first_table AS f3 ON f2.parent = f3.id
LEFT JOIN first_table AS f4 ON f3.parent = f4.id
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join queries for that.

```
SELECT firstTable.id, names, secondTable.id, idsub FROMfirstTable 
   LEFT JOIN secondTable ON firstTable.id = secondTable.idsub 
   LEFT JOIN thirdTable ON secondTable.subid = thirdTable.id
```

Comment: I want to display names for both id and idsub, ie. I have a relational table which I want to translate using the dictionary from another table.

Comment: You can join that table with these two and it will do the job.

Comment: but how do I do that?

Comment: but there is no third table the first one looks like this (1 John, 2 Mery, 3 Sam etc.) the second one has the hiararcy (children): (1 2, 3 1 etc.) denoting that Mery is John's child and that John is Sam's child. When I try to put the first table insted of third table in the code you provided I get Not unique table/alias for the first table

Comment: Then it's simple join query that I gave you yesterday.
SELECT name FROM first LEFT JOIN second ON first.id = second.subid